# Oracle Data Provider for .Net - No data querying

Tags: c#, oracle, cmd, dataset, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle Data Provider for .NET Assembly to query Oracle database.
Below is my code.

Though the code runs with no error. I don’t get data to my dataset dsOracleData.

However, when I run the query after connecting to SQL Developer, I can see the resulting data for the query.

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(“ConnectionString”)

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();

cmd.Connection = conn;

cmd.CommandText = Query1.ToString();


cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;


OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);

OracleCommandBuilder builder = new OracleCommandBuilder(adapter);

DataSet dsOracleData = new DataSet();

adapter.Fill(dsOracleData);
```

Comment: Did you try to add table mappings for DataSet? Like in this example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

Hi u can try like this,

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Your Connection string");

Conn.Open;

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("your select query");

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.Connection = conn;

using (OracleDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter())

{

  dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
  dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
}
```

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: OracleCommandBuilder automatically generates SQL statements for single-table updates when the SelectCommand property of the OracleDataAdapter is set.But he want to select data :)